# Converting R matrix into LaTeX matrix in the math or equation environment

Tags: r, latex, knitr

Let's say there is an R matrix `x`:

```
x <- structure(c(2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 17, 10, 18, 13), .Dim = c(5L,2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("X1", "X2")))
```

I am writing a report featuring LaTeX equations, using the Markdown-pandoc-LaTeX workflow. `x` is one of the matrices that need to appear in these equations. Is it possible to programmatically render the LaTeX respresentation of the matrix as follows?:

```
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 12\\ 
3 & 17\\ 
5 & 10\\ 
7 & 18\\ 
9 & 13
\end{bmatrix}
```

Ideally the report code would be something in the lines of:

```
\begin{displaymath}
\mathbf{X} = `r whatever-R-code-to-render-X`
\end{displaymath}
```

but this is probably cumbersome, so I will surely settle for the simple transformation.

Comment: P.S. Having asked this, I realized it would probably be not too difficult to write a custom function to do that, but perhaps the functionality already exists?

Comment: `Hmisc:::latex` what you're looking for?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the xtable packages print.xtable method with a simple wrapper script to set some default args.

```
bmatrix = function(x, digits=NULL, ...) {
  library(xtable)
  default_args = list(include.colnames=FALSE, only.contents=TRUE,
                      include.rownames=FALSE, hline.after=NULL, comment=FALSE,
                      print.results=FALSE)
  passed_args = list(...)
  calling_args = c(list(x=xtable(x, digits=digits)),
                   c(passed_args,
                     default_args[setdiff(names(default_args), names(passed_args))]))
  cat("\\begin{bmatrix}\n",
      do.call(print.xtable, calling_args),
      "\\end{bmatrix}\n")
}
```

Seems to do what you are looking for

```
x <- structure(c(2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 17, 10, 18, 13), .Dim = c(5L,2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("X1", "X2")))

bmatrix(x)
## \begin{bmatrix}
##   2.00 & 12.00 \\ 
##   3.00 & 17.00 \\ 
##   5.00 & 10.00 \\ 
##   7.00 & 18.00 \\ 
##   9.00 & 13.00 \\ 
##    \end{bmatrix}
```

And to use no decimal places like your example.

```
bmatrix(x, digits=0)
## \begin{bmatrix}
##   2 & 12 \\ 
##   3 & 17 \\ 
##   5 & 10 \\ 
##   7 & 18 \\ 
##   9 & 13 \\ 
##    \end{bmatrix}
```

Answer (score 9):

For a future reference, here is the function that I wrote myself later:

```
matrix2latex <- function(matr) {

printmrow <- function(x) {

    cat(cat(x,sep=" & "),"\\\\ \n")
}

cat("\\begin{bmatrix}","\n")
body <- apply(matr,1,printmrow)
cat("\\end{bmatrix}")
}
```

It doesn't require an external package. For some reason the `apply` produced NULL at the end of the output (the actual return?). This was solved by assigning the return to the `body` variable, which is otherwise of no use. The next task is to [render the output of that function in LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759444/knitr-r-code-within-latex-environment-in-a-markdown-document) within knitr.

Answer (score 1):

if anyone needs rounded matrices with **borders** via **`\bordermatrix`**, I appended @Maxim.K's function to that end.

```
m2l <- function(matr) {
    matr <- round(x = matr, digits = 2)  # sadly this is necessary because given this function, the options(digits = 2) does not work
    matr2 <- data.frame(c("~",rownames(matr)))  # add rownames
    for (r in colnames(matr)) {  # add col contents and colnames
      matr2 <- cbind(matr2, c(r, matr[,r]))
    }
    printmrow <- function(x) {
        ret <- paste(paste(x, collapse = " & "), "\\cr")
        sprintf(ret)
    }
    out <- apply(matr2, 1, printmrow)
    out2 <- paste("\\bordermatrix{", paste(out, collapse = ' '),"}")
    return(out2)
}
```

Pretty hideous code, I know, but get's the job done.

Maybe this'll be useful for someone out there.

Can look nice, especially for correlation matrices and such stuff:

[image: tex]

Comment: unfortunately, for some reason, the output works only when `render()`ing the `*.Rmd` to PDF (via LaTeX), not to HMTL (via Markdown).
Not sure why, raised it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740613/how-do-i-get-latex-math-typeset-matrix-with-borders-in-html-output-from-rmd