# Creating a latex matrix in R-markdown

Tags: r, matrix, latex

How should I modify this short program (with a random table):

````
```{r, results='tex'}
library(xtable)
A <- matrix(c(2,-5,4,1,-2.5,1,1,-4,6),byrow=T,nrow=3,ncol=3)
print(xtable(A), type="latex")
```
````

To get a latex matrix. The output now is:

[image: matrix]

and should be:

[image: matrix2]

Note: It **can't** be just done in this way:

```
$$\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{}\left[\begin{matrix}
2 & -5 & 4\\ 1 & -2.5 & 1\\ 1 & -4 & 6
\end{matrix}\right] 
\end{equation*}
$$
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting R matrix into LaTeX matrix in the math or equation environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20749444/converting-r-matrix-into-latex-matrix-in-the-math-or-equation-environment)